# Get adjacent fields with GROUP BY / MAX

Tags: sql, t-sql

This has probably been asked many times but I can't find a solution because I don't know how to phrase this question.

```
[product] [shop]  [price] [date]
Pizza     Shop1   10      2014-05-10
Pizza     Shop2   12      2014-05-04
Snow      Shop1   101     2014-05-02
Snow      Shop3   93      2014-05-11
```

I wish to query this table and get the price of the last added product:

```
[product] [shop]  [price] [date]
Pizza     Shop1   10      2014-05-10
Snow      Shop3   93      2014-05-11
```

An obviously wrong syntax:

```
SELECT
  product,
  shop WHERE MAX(date),
  price WHERE MAX(date),
  MAX(date)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY product
```

This query is already a part of a subquery so I want the best possible performing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER()` you can split the records in to partitions for each product, and assign each a row number, starting with 1 for the newest record for a partition (product).

Then you just select all the records with a row number of 1, for each product.

```
WITH
  sequenced AS
(
  SELECT
    myTable.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [product] ORDER BY [date] DESC)  AS product_date_ordinal
  FROM
    myTable
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  sequenced
WHERE
  product_date_ordinal = 1
```

This assumes SQL SERVER 2005 onwards, and you should have an index on `product, date DESC` for best performance.

Comment: really? That's the best readable solution? :-|  Lot's of new stuff for me!

Comment: Great tip on Partition by. Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @TieleDeclercq - Have a trigger or other mechanism to update records to mark them as "is_most_up_to_date" {0, 1}?  Then the whole CTE disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this aswell. Using join with subquery to filter your table, not as good as first answer I guess, but easier to read and understand:

```
SELECT Table.*
FROM Table
    RIGHT JOIN
    (
        SELECT product, max(date) AS date FROM Table
        GROUP BY product
    ) AS Filter
    ON Filter.product = Table.product AND Filter.date = Table.date
```

Just replace "Table" with the name of your table.

Comment: @Tiele Declercq Check out my edit, you may like it :)